# DNSSEC demployment: is delegation signer (DS) mandatory?

Tags: networking, security, dns

If I have an authoritative DNS serve and I deployed DNSSEC, as you may know, there is the Key Signing Key (KSK) and Zone Signing Key (ZSK). Is giving the KSK to the higher level DNS is mandatory?

What if my authoritative server is experimental and it is the only DNS (no higher DNS) and I want to implement DNSSEC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Most DNSSEC-capable resolvers allow you to specify trust anchors at any point, not just `.`. (However, many of them take configuration in DS record *format*.)

For example, in BIND you can manually add your DNSKEY as a [`trusted-keys{}`](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/dnssec-guide/html/dnssec-guide.html#trusted-keys-and-managed-keys) entry.